# okhttp websockets messages in recyclerview

Tags: android, websocket, android-recyclerview

i have a working implementation of a websocket adding data to a recyclerview, but my issue is that it's too much items being added and it's bogging down the performance of the app. When I add the items, they're being added on the UI thread. And I'm only keeping a max of 15 items in the list. As new items are added, the 16th item is removed. Would RxJava observables be better for this? Or should I just add every 10th item to the list and ignore the other 1000's of items added? Or are there any other recommendations to boost performance of items being added continuously?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you can pass the LifeCycleOwner and viewModel to the adapter then you can have something like this

```
  class ViewHolder(
    itemView: View,
    val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    val viewModel: MainViewModel
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private var previousLiveData: LiveData<MyData>? = null

    fun bindData(item: Item) {
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView)
        previousLiveData?.removeObservers(lifecycleOwner)
        previousLiveData = viewModel.getInfoFromLiveData(item.data)
        previousLiveData?.observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it.webSocketData
        })
    }

}
```